# Spring Data, JPA @ManyToOne lazy initialization not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know there are many similar questions about this trouble but nothing works for me.

I have **@ManyToOne** relationship between Aim and User.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private User user;
```

and

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private Collection<Aim> userAims;
```

respectively.

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and principal.user.isEnabled() == true")
public Aim findById(String aimId) throws NumberFormatException, EntityNotFoundException {
    Aim aim = null;
    try {
        aim = aimRepository.findOne(Long.parseLong(aimId));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    if (aim == null) throw new EntityNotFoundException("Aim with id: " + aimId + " not found!");
    return aim;
}
```

**@OneToMany** associations work fine with lazy fetching. Method isn't nested to another **@Transactional** method so **@Transactional** works fine.

 [image]


[image]

> So the record exists.

1. Classes **User** and **Aim** aren't **final** and implement
   **Serializable**
2. Some sources advice to put annotations on getters. It also doesn't
   work.
3. **@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)** the same situation =\
4. Query via Hibernate results the same, but HQL query with **left join
   fetch** works fine
5. My FK is **ON UPDATE  CASCADE ON INSERT CASCADE**
6. **optional = false** also tried...

> **Pay attention** that I haven't the **LazyInitException**

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing from the code in your `findById` method, and by the reference to "lazy initialization not working" in the title, that you are wanting to find an `Aim` object by it's numeric Id, along with the associated `User` object.

In order to do this with lazy-loading, you need to 'get' the associated object, and (most importantly) you need to 'get' one of the associated entity's fields.

So the code inside the `try` block should be:

```
aim = aimRepository.findOne(Long.parseLong(aimId));
if (aim != null && aim.getUser() != null) {
    aim.getUser().getUserId(); // doesn't need to be assigned to anything
}
```

Alternatively, if you have a logger available you can use the `userId` in a debug or trace log message:

```
if (aim != null && aim.getUser() != null) {
    logger.debug("Lazy-loaded User " + aim.getUser().getUserId());
}
```

This has the added benefit that you can debug how things are lazy-loaded.

By the way, we found out the hard way that making a find routine throw an Exception when it doesn't find something is a bad idea. This is because you might want to use the find routine to find out if an Entity does **NOT** exist. If that is happening within a transaction, your exception may trigger an unwanted rollback (unless you specifically ignore it). Better to return `null` and check for that instead of using a `try ... catch`.

Comment: thank you for you response. I'll reply to both of yours answers. I know that i need to get `User` explicitly by calling `aim.getUser()` but there is an image that i have attached that shows that i entered to debug mode. When you are in debug mode to see fields values IDE does an implicitly call to field(maybe via reflectcion) so my lazy initialization fires. After that i have an additional user request to DB as expected which means that it's lazy not eager. First thing i did when i've faced with this problem i tried to do explicit call `aim.getUser()` =))) , @DuncanKinnear

Comment: I tried your code and result still the same, @DuncanKinnear

Comment: It's not enough just to `GetUser`, you need to look at something inside the associated `User` object for the contents to be lazy-loaded. Can you post the code you have tried to do this? Have you tried logging as I suggest with additional debug log messages to display field values within the `User` object?

Comment: unbelievable.You saved me. But you are not absolutely right about lazy loading.To get lazy loaded obj i only need to fire getUser()....But I forgot that it returns proxy on my obj. Your `aim.getUser().getUserId()` code showed me that i have appropriate `userId` value. I somehow obsessed with the debugging window and with obj address particularly . Also i have made a mistake when user obj were used in my code. So that two mistakes mixed. Please, rewrite your answer with "Proxy" remembering that people could tie it. I'll mark it as best answer anyway. But `proxy` can make it easier to understand

Comment: @InsFi Could you elaborate on "Proxy"?  I also have a same issue... when I getUser() does not trigger Hibernate fetch...

Comment: @EricHuang I'm not sure I can recall. But as I remember fetch isn't called until you explicitly get something from that proxy obj. I.e. id or something. Another words proxy behaves like a wrapper and doesnt do anything until it's really needed. That's one of the reason to have `equals` depends on ids and not on references

Comment: @InsFi thanks for the quick response. So I guess you really do need `aim.getUser().getUserId()` to trigger the fetch... okey thanks a lot.  I was hopping I could just aim.getUser() so its cleaner on the code

Comment: This answer has so much great advice, and answers the question, that I just had to upvote and leave a comment of thanks. I've struggle with jpa and issues of this sort and this really helps make sense of it.